# MAGENTO PRODUCT CRON ERROR

Tags: cron

I have website in magento. i have upgraded version 1.9.1.1. to 1.9.3.1 successfully. but everday 1AM i got email with error message like.

Product alerts cron warnings: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'catalog_product_entity_group_price.is_percent' in 'field list', query was: SELECT `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`value_id` AS `price_id`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`website_id`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`all_groups`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`customer_group_id` AS `cust_group`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`value` AS `price`, `catalog_product_entity_group_price`.`is_percent` FROM `catalog_product_entity_group_price` WHERE (entity_id='3754') AND (website_id IN(0, '5'))

the table having "is_percent" field i dont know why it happen.

Please help me anyone

Thanks
Mohan NK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1/ In Magento 1.9.3.1 your Mage_Catalog module version should be 1.6.0.0.19.1.5

One of your updaters didn't run well when you updated Magento CE to 1.9.3.1 that's why you don't have **is_percent** field in **catalog_product_entity_group_price** table.

2/ Run this SQL query:

```
UPDATE core_resource SET version = '1.6.0.0.19.1.1', data_version = '1.6.0.0.19.1.1' WHERE code = 'catalog_setup';
```

3/ From Magento root folder remove your Magento Cache, run:

```
rm -rf var/cache/*
```

5/ From Magento root folder run updaters:

```
php index.php
```

6/ Run this SQL query to check what's your Mage_Catalog version now:

```
SELECT * FROM core_resource WHERE code = 'catalog_setup';
```

**If everything runs well it should be 1.6.0.0.19.1.5**

Comment: Thanks for reply i will try this. before doing this. i have a question                                1.  catalog_product_entity_group_price this table already having "is_percent". i want to delete the filed before following your instruction ?           2. i have upgraded version via "FTP".

Comment: Can you run this query in your database? 
`SELECT catalog_product_entity_group_price.value_id AS price_id, catalog_product_entity_group_price.website_id, catalog_product_entity_group_price.all_groups, catalog_product_entity_group_price.customer_group_id AS cust_group, catalog_product_entity_group_price.value AS price, catalog_product_entity_group_price.is_percent FROM catalog_product_entity_group_price WHERE (entity_id='3754') AND (website_id IN(0, '5'))`

Comment: AFTER RUNNING THE QUERY I GOT THIS "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0004 sec )"

Comment: Run this query and show result please: `SELECT * FROM core_resource WHERE code = 'catalog_setup';`

Comment: After running the above query i got this "catalog_setup 1.6.0.0.19.1.5 1.6.0.0.19.1.5       "

Comment: If you install https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler module you will be able to run your product alert cron manually and check if everything is ok.

Comment: Thanks for you reply i have already installed this extension. what my question was iam getting email with error message everyday cron runs at 1am with the above error. what can i do now ? i want follow above your solution ? i dotnt know where it setup. i have reviewed backend system-->configuration-->catalog-->product alert run setting.  i just changed email id but it's still coming to old email id. i dont know where it's coming from.

Comment: When you run this cron manually, do you receive an error email?

Comment: Actually i dont know how to run manually. i can see this extension in system-->scheduler-->Job Configuration-->Available Jobs. here i can see list of cons. which one i want to run and how to run this ?

Comment: Search for `product_alert` and run it manually.

Comment: you mean "catalog_product_alert" this one ?

Comment: Exactly, run it.

Comment: After running successfully. i got this messages                                       "Ran "catalog_product_alert" (Duration: 9 sec)
"catalog_product_alert" messages:
---RETURN_VALUE---
Mage_ProductAlert_Model_Observer
Scheduler is working. (Last heart beat: 3 minute(s) ago)"

Comment: Check system.log or exception.log if everything is ok.

Comment: Checking the system.log do you think anything wrong with that message above. i mean any issue

Comment: Has cron completed successfully?

Comment: Hi..there is no error related to this in exception and system.log. i think it's seems like working your solution.anyway i will wait for tomorrow.

Comment: I have one more query can i ask here ?

Comment: If it's about your initial request yes of course :)

Comment: Actually i have duplicate product url in sitemap. for example  www.test.com/test is the product url, but i have lot of url like www.test.com/test-1 and www.test.com/test-2 like this. please help me how to resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you please open a new question cause it's a différent topic. Thank you.

Comment: this is the url for the new topic please check and help me "http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/160117/magento-product-url-duplicate-in-sitemap".